# Why the histogram doesn't work - shiny library in R

Tags: r, shiny

Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/mirichoi0218/insurance

Hi, I have a problem with shiny library. Wanted to create app that will show the Charges depending on the age, region and children. Unfortunately, the histogram doesn't work.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Insurance charges"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("ageInput", "Age", 18, 64, 41),
      radioButtons("childrenInput", "Liczba dzieci",
                   choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3",'4','5'),
                   selected = "0"),
      selectInput("regionInput", "Region",
                  choices = c("NE", "NW", "SE","SW"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot"),
      br(), br(),
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      insurance %>%
      filter(age >= input$ageInput[1],
             age <= input$ageInput[2],
             children == input$childrenInput,
             region == input$regionInput
      )
    ggplot(filtered, aes(insurance$charges)) +
      geom_histogram()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read how to produce an MCVE. Specify the problem and describe the desired result and your attempts to reach it.

Comment: `ggplot(filtered, aes(insurance$charges))` is wrong and likely comes with clear errors (that you've not included in your question). Perhaps you meant `ggplot(filtered, aes(charges))`? What you've done is akin to `ggplot(mtcars, aes(1:3))`. The aesthetic you've assigned is very likely not the same length as the data that `ggplot` intends to use, so `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (32): x` should be a clear error. If you are not getting *that* error, then please don't keep it a secret from us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major issue with your code is that

- you map `insurance$charges` on `x` in `ggplot()`. That's why you always get a histogram for the total dataset. Simply use `aes(charges)` to use the column from your `filtered` dataset.
- Not sure about that. Maybe your recoded your data, but the regions in the Kaggle dataset have labels "northeast", "northwest", .... To account for that you could use a named vector for the `choices` in the `selectInput`
- Finally, you have to use a vector of length 2 for the `value` of the `sliderInput` to get a range slider.

And as an example on how to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I used a random fake dataset for the reprex.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Insurance charges"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("ageInput", "Age", min = 18, max = 64, value = c(18, 41)),
      radioButtons("childrenInput", "Liczba dzieci",
        choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
        selected = "0"
      ),
      selectInput("regionInput", "Region",
        choices = c("NE" = "northeast", "NW" = "northwest", "SE" = "southeast", "SW" = "southwest")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot"),
      br(), br(),
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <- insurance %>%
      filter(
        age >= input$ageInput[1],
        age <= input$ageInput[2],
        children == input$childrenInput,
        region == input$regionInput
      )

    ggplot(filtered, aes(charges)) +
      geom_histogram()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

insurance <- data.frame(
  age = sample(18:64, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  children = sample(0:5, 1000, replace = TRUE),
  region = sample(c("southwest", "southeast", "northwest", "northeast"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  charges = runif(1000, 3000, 40000)
)
```